# How to place each nested json into sql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following php done

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('ourfile.json');
 //convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//pull all job assignments 
$jobassignresults = array();
foreach($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk){
    $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
    $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
    $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
    $jatechfinished = array($jatechid, $jatechname);
    $jobassignreults[] = $jatechfinished;
}
$jasplit = $data['jobAssignments']['split'];
```

I am now working to place that data into mysql with the following code started

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO table1(jobassignresults,
```

I can not for the life of me figure out how to put the list of each tech listed into the sql database.

The json looks like this

```
"jobAssignments": [
{
  "id": 15797,
  "jobId": 15792,
  "jobNumber": "15792",
  "technician": {
    "id": 156,
    "name": "Mike"
  },
```

Comment: use `json_decode()` of php.

Comment: @aldrin27 i added the top of my file, sorry i had cut that out

Comment: Your insert sql is not finished. `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2)
VALUES (value1,value2);`

Comment: @aldrin27 i understand it isnt finished, im not sure how i should go about finishing it since the number of techs could be between 1 and 5 thats what i am trying to find out, what is the best way to structure it so that the techs load in

Comment: So you just want to insert all techs in the database?

Comment: @aldrin27 yes i want to insert it all including all possible techs

Comment: Try my answer. If it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try my answer if it works. I loop the data and then for every looped data I insert it to the database.

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('ourfile.json');
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//pull all job assignments 

$jobassignresults = array();
$jatech = array(); //initiate variable

foreach($data['jobAssignments'] as $chunk){
  $jatech = $chunk['technician'];
  $jatechid = $jatech['id'];
  $jatechname = $jatech['name'];
  $jatechfinished = array($jatechid, $jatechname);
  $jobassignreults[] = $jatechfinished;
}

foreach($jatech as $key => $techs) //loop every data and insert.
{
   $sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ('id','name') VALUES ($techs['id'], $techs['name']);";
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a shot once i finish typing it all up! you rock!

Comment: A) You're only defining a SQL query, not executing it. B) You're not using placeholder values so none of those things are escaped properly and this won't work.

Comment: Yes I know. I'm just showing him how to insert it in database. I'm only finishing his sql query. And I don't know if he uses mysqli or PDO. So Im just assuming.